# jquery-ui-map how to set zoom level

Tags: jquery, google-maps, jquery-ui-map

I have the following code working fine, but I'm unable to add a zoom level. According to the [docs](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-ui-map/wiki/jquery_ui_map_v_3_sample_code) it should work with `'option', 'zoom', 7` but this gives an error: `"$("#map_canvas").gmap("option", "zoom", 7).bind is not a function"`

Working code, sans zoom, edited. Zoom is always at 1.

```
$("#map_trigger").click(function(){
        var prop_id = $("#map_canvas").attr("rel");
        $('#map_canvas').gmap({'zoom':6}).bind('init', function(evt, map) {
            $.getJSON( basepath+'properties/get_gps_coords/'+prop_id, function(data) {
                $.each( data.markers, function(i, m) {
                    lat = m.latitude;
                    longitude = m.longitude;
                    $('#map_canvas').gmap(
                        'addMarker', { 'position': new google.maps.LatLng(lat, m.longitude), 'bounds':true }
                    );
                });
            });
        });
    });
```

How can I add a zoom level to this snippet?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use:

```
$("#map_canvas").gmap({'zoom':7})
```

The option-method can be used when the map is already initialized and will not return a jQuery-object, so it's not chainable(what will explain the error you got).

Comment: It's not maximum, it's the necessary zoom to show all markers, because you set 'bounds' to true inside the marker-creation. set bounds to false and set the center of the map to the marker-position instead

Answer (score 9):

This code works for me:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-language" content="es">
        <meta charset="utf-8">

        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script> 
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../ui/jquery.ui.map.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div style="height: 500px; width:500px;" id="map_canvas"></div>
        <button id="btnChangeZoom">change zoom</button>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $('#map_canvas').gmap({ 'center': '40.33238,-3.76546','scrollwheel':false});
            $('#map_canvas').gmap('option', 'mapTypeId', google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE);
            $('#map_canvas').gmap('option', 'zoom', 17);
            });

        $("#btnChangeZoom").click(function(){changeZoom()});

        function changeZoom(){
            $('#map_canvas').gmap('option', 'zoom', 10);
        }   
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Yo need to center the map and then zoom it. Here is a sample of code

```
$('#map_canvas').gmap({'center': '43.1502, 25.02083'})
$('#map_canvas').gmap('option', 'zoom', 10);
$('#map_canvas').gmap('addMarker', {'position': '43.1502, 25.02083', 'icon': '/picnic/img/Pin.png'}).click(function() {
    //$('#map_canvas').gmap('openInfoWindow', {'content': 'Hello World!'}, this);
});
```